# Override controller level Authorization value in .NET Core

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-authorization

I have the following controller which implements a generic one with all the endpoints available. All but one endpoint should be accesible ONLY by `admins` or `superadmins` therefore I decorated the controller level as follows:

```
[Route("my-entity")]
[ActiveUsers]
[Authorize(Roles = "admin,superadmin")]
public class MyEntityController : ItemControllerBase<MyEntity, MyEntitySearch>
{
    public WorkCentersController(IItemGetByIdManager<MyEntity> itemGetByIdManager,
                                 IItemSearchManager<MyEntity, MyEntitySearch> searchItemManager) 
                               : base(itemGetByIdManager,
                                      searchItemManager)
        {
        }

        [HttpPost("search-summaries")]
        [Authorize(Roles = "admin,superadmin,company-admin")]
        public override async Task<IActionResult> SearchAsync([FromBody] MyEntitySearch search)
        {
            return await base.SearchAsync(search);
        }
    }
```

I then overrode the method I want to apply a loose authorization filter and added the override calling just the base and adding the `company-admin` role I would like to authorize. That however is failing because of the DefaultAuthorizationService because it says IsInRole should be either `admin` or `superadmin`. I thought I could override methods with different authorization policies however I don't know what would be the set up in this case for the authorization to work.

```
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer.JwtBearerHandler[2]
      Successfully validated the token.
dbug: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer.JwtBearerHandler[8]
      AuthenticationScheme: Bearer was successfully authenticated.
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.DefaultAuthorizationService[2]
      Authorization failed. These requirements were not met:
      RolesAuthorizationRequirement:User.IsInRole must be true for one of the following roles: (admin|superadmin)
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer.JwtBearerHandler[13]
      AuthenticationScheme: Bearer was forbidden.
dbug: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel[9]
      Connection id “0HM6SOE66UCO7” completed keep alive response.
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Diagnostics[2]
```

I would like to avoid the creation of a new controller will all but this operation in order to save code duplication and I'm faily sure this can be achieved.

Any input is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Do you mean that user as `company-admin` role can not access `SearchAsync` action?

Comment: Exactly that’s the issue

Comment: Please note the attributes are chained together and applied controller then action in order, it seems be expected behavior. You can try to remove `[Authorize(Roles = "admin,superadmin")]` from controller level and apply it on other action(s).

Comment: I ended up doing that and overriding the base clase with admin,superadmin roles. It seemed a way to achieve it. Thanks!